# Creating Snowpark Session using account with SSO

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpark

I'm working on a Snowpark project using the Python API. My Snowflake account requires SSO, so I've used the SSO method to get connected, but I'm having issues with there being no defined session. How do I fix this so that I can start working with this data?

My SSO code:

```
import snowflake.connector
import sys
con = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user=<"username">, 
    account=<account name">,
    authenticator="externalbrowser",
)
cur = con.cursor()
print(sys.executable)
print(sys.version)
print(sys.version_info)
try:
    cur.execute("select current_date")
    one_row=cur.fetchone()
    print("Current_Date:",one_row[0])
    cur.execute("SELECT current_version()")
    one_row = cur.fetchone()
    print("Snowfalke_Version:",one_row[0])
finally:
    cur.close()
cur.close()
```

First query run:

```
provider_table= session.table("ENVIRONMENT.<view name>")
```

And I get this error:
NameError: name 'session' is not defined

I admit that I know that I don't define "session" prior to calling it -- I'm just not sure of the method to do so. Anyone know? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The session should be initialized and then used in the code as detailed here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/creating-session.html#creating-a-session

Comment: When I use that method, I get a Key Error with my account name. I just inserted it with "" I'm not sure if this is related to the fact that my account requires SSO.

Comment: Not sure if the code posted in the initial thread has typos but a sample Python code using Snowflake connector is here : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-install.html#step-2-verify-your-installation

Answer (score 1):

To create a Snowpark Python session using SSO, pass `externalbrowser` to the `AUTHENTICATOR` parameter in your `connection_parameters` dictionary:

```py
from snowflake.snowpark import Session

def snowpark_sso_connection() -> Session:
    connection_parameters = {
        "ACCOUNT": "<your snowflake account>",
        "USER": "<your snowflake user>",
        "AUTHENTICATOR": "externalbrowser",
    }
    session = Session.builder.configs(connection_parameters).create()
    return session

session = snowpark_sso_connection()

print(session.sql("SELECT CURRENT_ACCOUNT(),CURRENT_USER()").show())
```

Running the above program will open your browser for SSO authentication:

```bash
Initiating login request with your identity provider. A browser window should have opened for you to complete the login. If you can't see it, check existing browser windows, or your OS settings. Press CTRL+C to abort and try again...
Going to open: <your sso url> to authenticate...
```

[image: Snowpark SSO Browser Auth]

Output:

```bash
--------------------------------------------------
|"CURRENT_ACCOUNT()"      |"CURRENT_USER()"      |
--------------------------------------------------
|<your snowflake account> |<your snowflake user> |
--------------------------------------------------
```

**Make sure you have Snowpark Python installed before running the above**:

> - [Setting Up Your Development Environment for Snowpark Python](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/setup)