# Creating Snowpark Session using account with SSO - Snowflake connector method is not working

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, single-sign-on

I'm working on a Snowpark project using the Python Snowflake API.
My organization has setup Snowflake SSO authentication, so I need to use this method to login to my snowflake account.

To connect to Snowflake using your IDE and Python, you would use the Python connector (https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-install#step-2-verify-your-installation).

I can easily authenticate with this method using the below code:

```
from snowflake.snowpark import Session
import snowflake.connector

ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
user='<username>',
account='<account>',
authenticator='externalbrowser'
)
```

With this code what I'm getting is a `snowflake.connector.connection.SnowflakeConnection` object. I can access all its available attributes and methods (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-api).

However, when using snowpark I need a `snowflake.snowpark.Session` object (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/creating-session#creating-a-session). In the documentation it is stated that

> "To authenticate, you use the same mechanisms that the Snowflake Connector for Python supports."

The problem here is that I don't know how to "connect" my snowpark Session object to use the SSO that I setup with my python connector. I need it to perform all Snowpark operations leveraging the Snowpark API.

A similar question has been posted before but has not been answered: [Creating Snowpark Session using account with SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73376083/creating-snowpark-session-using-account-with-sso)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the same mechanism as for the Python connector should work for a Snowpark session.

It should work as something like:

```python
connection_parameters = {
    "account": "accountname",
    "user": "username",
    "authenticator": "externalbrowser"
}  
new_session = Session.builder.configs(connection_parameters).create()
```

[Doc reference.](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/creating-session#creating-a-session)

Comment: Thanks, this did indeed work. Sorry this a new account so I can upvote your comment (yet).

Comment: @NicolasSanchez no worries. I am glad to know that it worked for you. You still can mark the answer as “accepted” though. It will help others too.